# How to join two sub queries and find the difference of attribute values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From the below query, I want to know how to combine these two sub-queries and also find the difference of values of the attributes specified for two different years.

I had tried joining them using joins, but I do not have a common attribute on which I can combine them as they are for two different years. I need to find the difference in order to compute the change as seen in the attached picture. Can anyone help?

```
(select (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD,1,4)))-1 as 'Year1',
   SUM(CASE WHEN dh.HOME = 'f' THEN 1 else 0 END) as 'foriegn1',
   SUM(CASE WHEN dh.HOME = 'o' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS 'outofstate1',
   SUM(CASE WHEN dh.HOME = 'i' THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS 'texas1',
   SUM(CASE WHEN dh.HOME = 'u' THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS 'Unknown1',

   COUNT(*) as Totalenrollment
   FROM dw_enrollment_F d
   inner join dim_Time t
   on d.TIME_KEY = t.TIME_KEY
   inner join dim_Home dh
   on d.HOME_KEY = dh.HOME_KEY
   inner join dim_Student_Level sl
   on d.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY = sl.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY
   where t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all =20162
  and t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD_ALL not in('20157','20165','20168','20169','20167')
   GROUP BY (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD,1,4)) ) -1) 


   (select (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD,1,4)))-1 as 'Year2',
   SUM(CASE WHEN dh.HOME = 'f' THEN 1 else 0 END) as 'foriegn2',
   SUM(CASE WHEN dh.HOME = 'o' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS 'outofstate2',
   SUM(CASE WHEN dh.HOME = 'i' THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS 'texas2',
   SUM(CASE WHEN dh.HOME = 'u' THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS 'Unknown2',
   COUNT(*) as Totalenrollment2
   FROM dw_enrollment_F d
   inner join dim_Time t
   on d.TIME_KEY = t.TIME_KEY
   inner join dim_Home dh
   on d.HOME_KEY = dh.HOME_KEY
   inner join dim_Student_Level sl
   on d.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY = sl.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY
   where t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all = 20172
  and t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD_ALL not in('20157','20165','20168','20169','20167')
   GROUP BY (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD,1,4)) ) -1)
```

[image]

Comment: can you please specify database thanks

Comment: your query is different from your result.

Comment: Why not just paste the results into Excel and calculate the difference?

Comment: If you don't have a common field on which to join then how can you ever know how to associate the rows from the two subqueries? If you do know what the association should be then you need to add it to your question (or, even better, join your subqueries based on your logic for this association)